# Thread pool for interdependent tasks

Tags: c++, multithreading, threadpool

I have a problem that is well served by a thread pool in the nonrecursive case and it would benefit greatly from tasks (the work/function given to the pool) being able to add more tasks to the pool. The problem with my thread pool implementation is that the first level of tasks fills all the worker threads, creates the second level of tasks, then blocks while it waits for the second level tasks to finish. Since all worker threads are blocked waiting on the second level to finish, the second level tasks never get executed, thus the whole program deadlocks.

Are there any general solutions to this? Possibly a preemptive thread pool (if that's even possible). I did think of having tasks be explicitly prioritized, but the problem with that is that it doesn't automatically handle dependencies; it requires more work on the API user.

Thanks in advance for any insight or suggestions.

EDIT: thread pool class def

```
class{
public:
    thread_pool() = delete;
    thread_pool(const thread_pool&) = delete;
    thread_pool(unsigned int threads);
    ~thread_pool();

    template<class T, class... Args>
    std::future<T>
    async(std::function<T(Args...)>&& f, Args&&... args);

    template<class... Args>
    std::future<void>
    async(std::function<void(Args...)>&& f, Args&&... args);

    template<class T>
    std::future<T>
    async(std::function<T()>&& f);

    std::future<void>
    async(std::function<void()>&& f);

protected:
    void init_threads();
    void join_threads();
};
```

Comment: How does the blocking map?  Does one first-level task create one second-level task, or more?

Comment: Please clarify: you have created your own thread pool, not using one that's supplied by your runtime environment or development environment?

Comment: @Martin: Each nth level task can add arbitrarily many n+1th level tasks.

Comment: @Jim: It's my implementation. It's functionally equivalent to std::async, but executed with a fixed number of threads. (To prevent over-scheduling in the case of deep recursion.) I'll post the API, but the code is long and probably unnecessary clutter. But if you would like to see it, I can post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a fixed number of threads to prevent the case of too many *active* tasks at the same time, but when a first-level task waits for a second-level one, that thread is no longer *active*, so it should no longer count towards the fixed number of running threads.

The way i see it you have two ways of working around this:

1. Mark the thread as *busy* when waiting for another task and tells the thread pool that it can temporarily create a new thread to replace it. (this is similar to the Windows Thread Pool [CallbackMayRunLong](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681981%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function).
2. Use a *task done callback* to resume the first-level task after the second-level one(s) finish instead of waiting for them. (similar to how you would use *tasks* in javascript).

Although more complex, the second option is much more flexible and std::bind gives you a few options for preserving state between those callbacks